# How to get rgb value by cimg?

Tags: c++, image-processing, cimg

```
CImg<unsigned char> src("image.jpg");
int width = src.width();
int height = src.height();
unsigned char* ptr = src.data(10,10);
```

How can I get `rgb` from `ptr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the CImg documentation](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/CImg_reference.pdf) -- section 6.13 on page 34, and section 8.1.4.16 on page 120 -- it looks like the `data` method can take **four arguments**: x, y, z, and c:

```
T* data(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y = 0, 
        const unsigned int z = 0, const unsigned int c = 0)
```

...where `c` refers to the color channel.  I'm guessing that if your image is indeed an RGB image, then using values of 0, 1, or 2 for `c` will give you the red, green, and blue components at a given `x, y` location.

For example:

```
unsigned char *r = src.data(10, 10, 0, 0);
unsigned char *g = src.data(10, 10, 0, 1);
unsigned char *b = src.data(10, 10, 0, 2);
```

(But this is just a guess!)

**Edit:**

It looks like there's also an operator() for CImg that works in a similar manner:

```
unsigned char r = src(10, 10, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Have you tried operator(), e.g. unsigned char r = src(10,10,0,0);

Comment: Really depends on your image, but the r g and b channels are split, so reading one channel will get you the red value (ie, channel 0 with a jpg image), channel 1 will get you green, and channel 2 will get you blue...  theres an example that does it with a float image in the docs in section 8.1.4.9.. change the floats into unsigned chars and it should work...  Heres an example

   unsigned char r = src.data(10,10,0,0);
   unsigned char g = src.data(10,10,0,1);
   unsigned char b = src.data(10,10,0,2);

Comment: @wamp: I'd guess that grayscale images have a single channel of data per pixel, and that you'd be able to access that value in exactly the same way that you'd access the "red" component of an RGB image.  E.g. `char v = src(10, 10, 0, 0);`

Comment: How to determine whether it's rgb or grayscale image with cimg?

Comment: @user198729: It looks like the `spectrum` method returns the number of color channels.  So `int numChannels = src.spectrum();` might set `numChannels` to 3 for an RGB image, whereas it might be 1 for a grayscale image.

Answer (score 7):

Tested on Ubuntu 10.04 with a handmade 3x3 RGB image saved as `test.png`:

```
sudo apt-get install cimg-dev
```

Source file `cimg_test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <CImg.h>
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
    CImg<unsigned char> src("test.png");
    int width = src.width();
    int height = src.height();
    cout << width << "x" << height << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
            cout << "(" << r << "," << c << ") ="
                 << " R" << (int)src(c,r,0,0)
                 << " G" << (int)src(c,r,0,1)
                 << " B" << (int)src(c,r,0,2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ cimg_test.cpp -lX11 -lpthread -o cimg_test

./cimg_test 
3x3
(0,0) = R0 G0 B0
(0,1) = R255 G0 B0
(0,2) = R0 G255 B0
(1,0) = R0 G0 B255
(1,1) = R128 G128 B128
(1,2) = R0 G0 B128
(2,0) = R128 G0 B0
(2,1) = R0 G128 B0
(2,2) = R255 G255 B255
```

It works.

Comment: @wamp: src(c,r,0,0) is the 0-255 value of your gray scale image (r,c) pixel.

Comment: The explicit (int) call was critical in my application. Thanks for providing this answer!

Comment: After almost 11 years... you're welcome, @so860! :D

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to access data is with the `()` operator:

```
unsigned char r = img(10,10,0,0);
unsigned char g = img(10,10,0,1);
unsigned char b = img(10,10,0,2);
```

You are probably hitting confusion because CImg stores the raw data non-interleaved. i.e. your raw data is stored `R1, R2, ..., G1, G2, ..., B1, B2, ...` instead of `R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2, ...` see: http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__storage.html

`.data()` just returns a pointer, so to access the data directly as above you would do:

```
CImg<unsigned char> src("image.jpg");
int width = src.width();
int height = src.height();
unsigned char* ptr = src.data(10,10);
unsigned char r = ptr[0];
unsigned char g = ptr[0+width*height];
unsigned char b = ptr[0+2*width*height];
```

Answer (score -1):

@wamp: I don't know about CImg but grayscale images in RGB have:

R = G = B

and in CMYK:

C = M = Y = 0

K = luminance

So you don't even need a function for that...

Comment: This is not true.  While you can have an image saved in RGB format that uses only R=G=B, you will be using 3x as much data as necessary to store the image.  That's why there's a grayscale format for images that saves only one channel.